# Security proof in pairing based cryptography

Tags: provable-security, pairings

Let :

$G_{0}$ and $G_{1}$ be two multiplicative cyclic groups of prime order $p$,  $g$ be a generator of $G_{0}$ and $e$ be a bilinear map,

$e : G_0 \times G_0 → G_1$

and let $_{1} = ^{_{1}} $, $ _{2} = ^{_{2}} $ , ... , $ _{}= ^{_{}} $; 
$ =^{(+)/} $

such that $\alpha, \beta, r, s_{1}, s_{2}, ..., s_{n} \in Z_{p}$

Given $s_{x} \in Z_{p}$ ($x \neq i, i=1, ..., n$), and knowing $e\left( C_{1}, D\right), e\left( C_{2}, D\right), ..., e\left( C_{n}, D\right)$. I would like to know if it is possible to compute the value of $e(C_{x},D)$ and/or $D$.

Secret elements: $D$, $e(C_{x},D)$.

Public elements: $_{1}$, $_{2}$, ..., $_{n}$, $_{x}$, $e(C_{1},D)$, $e(C_{2},D)$, ..., $e(C_{n},D)$.

If it is not possible, how to prove that?

Comment: what is $C_x$? Of course if you know $C_x$.What is known to the attacker?What is public and secret?

Comment: In my question, the value of $D$ is kept secret.

Comment: @curious : I have just updated my question.

Comment: I think your question is a bit difficult to read because your notation is more difficult than necessary. If you want, you can also write such things just saying like: "Knowing $g^a,g^b$, is it possible to compute $g^{ab}$?". So you don't need all the $C$s and the $D$s. (But I would not change the current question now.)

Answer (score 1):

The only way i can see to evaluate $e(C_x,D)$ is to recover $D$ from a previous known pairing $e(C_i,D)$. However due to the [Fixed Argument Pairing Inversion 1 assumption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/256.pdf) this is computationally hard.

Comment: Is it possible to prove that in a formal manner?

Comment: It is more than straightforward i think following the reductionist approach

Comment: you could try to find a relation between $C_x$ and the $C_i$ which will be translated into $G_1$

Comment: @FlorianBourse even if there is a correlation in $C_x-C_i$, still you have to recover D

Comment: Not if you just want to compute $e(C_x,D)$

Comment: @curious For example, if we assume the correlation $C_x = C_1 \cdot C_2$, then $e(C_x, D) = e(C_1,D) \cdot e(C_2, D)$, and there is no need to compute $D$. Of course, you have to assume there is some correlation...

Comment: What if $C_{i}$ and $C_{x}$ are kept secret from the attacker? So he cannot verify if there is a correlation in $C_{x} - C_{i}$.

Comment: @FlorianBourse, What if $C_{i}$ and $C_{x}$ are kept secret from the attacker? So he cannot verify if there is a correlation in $C_{x}−C_{i}$.

Comment: @watou I don't really know, the only way to know if there is an attack is to formally prove the security. What I am saying is that an argument such as: "the only way i can see..." will never make a proof.